# Views are not ordered anymore

Tags: sql-server, database

I have inherited a site that worked fine until this weekend.  DB is MSSQL and the symptoms are that the record sets returned by the queries  don't make sense anymore.  I checked the tables and the data is there.  After investigating a bit I realized that the ORDER BY clause does not get executed anymore on all the views even when using TOP. Everything worked fine before.  What happened?

Comment: If you can show some sample db data and your query, we can help.

Comment: Does your query include an `order by`? If not, then everything works as expected. Rows in a relational database are **not** "sorted". The only way you can get a specific order is to use an `order by`.

Comment: All the views have the TOP and ORDER BY clause.  By I just read the answer below and now have to investigatebif they did indeed upgrade SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't sort views, by design.  Views are are not responsible for presenting your data.   They don't hold any data.
Now to answer your question of what happened?  Microsoft allowed the use of TOP and ORDER BY to work in older versions MSSQL while no other DBMS did.  With the newer version, and I bet that's what happened to you over the weekend  - they upgraded your server, this is no longer a possibility.

Here is more info by the expert
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/why-does-order-by-not-belong-in-a-view

To fix this you have to move the ORDER BY clause out of the view and use it in your query.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! If it's the case, that would blow... Is there a quick way to know what SQL server version is running?

Comment: @Bashful, use `SELECT @@VERSION`.  Also, kill the person who created the views with ORDER BY in the first place.  The ordering behavior was never guaranteed but some thought it was the proper behavior when it seemed to work on older versions.

Comment: Thanks sandman you were right. They upgraded to SQL server 2012... Here goes my Superbowl evening...  Thanks Dan.